# 'symlink error' trying to create a virtual environment with Python

Tags: android, python

python -m venv ll-env
Unable to symlink '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python' to '/storage/sdcard0/codde/code/lnlog/ll-env/bin/python'
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/sdcard0/codde/code/lnlog/ll-env/bin/python'
$

That's the error statement above. I'm using Termux on a Wiko Slide2.
I don't know what's wrong. Am using Python36 with the latest version of virtualenv installed with pip from the shell. I received similar errors when I tried using virtualenv.

I'm just learning to use Django and I want to continue when I'm not near my computer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're learning to use Django, you're probably better off just reading about it on your phone and apply when you get home, rather than trying to overcome all the peculiarities of android to force it to run software it's clearly not designed for. You'll save yourself a lot of time and headaches.